# Scala - Pattern Matching MatchError

Tags: scala

I'm playing with pattern matching, but I have some difficult to understand what's wrong with this piece of code:

```
class Expr {
  case class Number(v : Int) extends Expr
  case class Sum(a : Expr, b : Expr) extends Expr

  def show(e: Expr): String = {
    e match {
      case Number(a) => a.toString() 
      case Sum(a, b) => "(" + show(a) + "+" + show(b) + ")"
    }
  }

  override def toString() = show(this)
}

class Number(v : Int) extends Expr 

class Sum(a : Expr, b : Expr) extends Expr 

object Number {
  def apply(v : Int) = new Number(v)
}
object Sum extends Expr {
  def apply(a : Expr, b : Expr) = new Sum(a, b)
}

object ExpressionProblem {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val p =  Sum( Number(3),  Number(4))
    println( p )
  }
}
```

When I try to execute `println` it throws a MatchError.

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: an instance of class week4.Expr$Sum
    at week4.Expr.show(ExpressionProblem.scala:8)
    at week4.Expr.toString(ExpressionProblem.scala:14)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
    at scala.Console$.println(Console.scala:148)
    at scala.Predef$.println(Predef.scala:315)
    at week4.ExpressionProblem$.main(ExpressionProblem.scala:31)
    at week4.ExpressionProblem.main(ExpressionProblem.scala)
```

Comment: you're sending an instance of your `Sum` class, but trying to match an instance of `Sum` *case class*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're sending an instance of your `Sum` class, but trying to match an instance of `Sum` *case class*. Remove classes and make case classes visible to your code:

```
trait Expr {  
  def show(e: Expr): String = e match {
    case Number(a) => a.toString() 
    case Sum(a, b) => "(" + show(a) + "+" + show(b) + ")"
  }

  override def toString() = show(this)
}

case class Number(v : Int) extends Expr
case class Sum(a : Expr, b : Expr) extends Expr

object ExpressionNoProblem {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val p = Sum(Number(3), Number(4))
    println(p)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I don't get the point, could you please explain what's the difference?

Comment: you defined Sum (and Number) twice: once as an inner case class `Expr#Sum` another time - as a regular class `Sum`. Your matching was trying to match a `case class` (`Expr#Sum`), but you were actually sending an instance of class (`Sum`). Similar names but completely different classes

Comment: Besides, regular classes can't pattern match with `unapply`-style (extractors) `case Sum(a,b)` - they can only match as a type `case s: Sum`. See, http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html